# How can I use the result of a .then() function in another function in angularfire?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I need to access the user.uid for the logged in user from a function so that I can pass it into a Firebase ref.

Updated code based on comments:

```
var populateTasks = function(date){
  var promise = getKey();
  promise.then(function(user){
    $scope.ref = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/users/"+user.uid+"/tasks/" + getWeekStart(date) );
    var sync = $firebase($scope.ref);
    var week = sync.$asArray();
    $scope.week = week;
  });
};

function getKey(){
  return simpleLogin.getUser();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @EmptyPockets! I know you've resolved this, but for the sake of future posts, I'd like to point out that there's not really enough context here for devs to work through this with you. For example, where does simpleLogin.getUser() come from? (presumably from angularFire-seed which isn't mentioned here). Also, a better approach than this would be to use [resolve in your routes](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-routes), and then not have to worry about whether the user is loaded.

Comment: @Kato thanks, will do for next time. For my latest question I posted a Plunkr that has all of the related info. I think I'll do that for my future posts. Thanks for all the help you've given on stackoverflow. You don't have a blog or anything do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the promise in `getKey()`, then call `then()` on the returned promise in `populateTasks()` to access the result.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How do I return the promise in get key? return $promise?

Comment: @EmptyPockets: `then()` returns a promise, so you just need to return that: `return ....then(...);`

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to this. Can you please explain any further? return simpleLogin.getUser().then(function(user){});

Comment: Yes; that's exactly what you need.  What don't you understand?

Comment: That seems to return this {then: function, catch: function, finally: function}catch: function (callback) {finally: function (callback) {then: function (callback, errback, progressback) {__proto__: Object but I need to get user.uid.

Comment: @EmptyPockets: Yes; that's a promise.  You need to call `then()` on the promise to asynchronously use the value.

Comment: I edited the code above to show what I'm doing now. I think I'm missing some critical component here. How can I pass "user" into $scope.ref?

Comment: You can't; it's asynchronous (it doesn't exist yet).  You need to do everything inside the callback.

Comment: Unfortunately "user" is undefined the way I have it. I edited the code above again.

Comment: You're returning `undefined` from the `then()` callback in `getKey()`.  You should remove the `then()` call entirely if you don't want to return something different.

Comment: Updated again. But now I cannot access $scope.weeks outside of that callback. Am I doing something fundamentally incorrect here?

Comment: @EmptyPockets: It's **async**.  It doesn't exist yet.  You can't do that.

Comment: Sorry, please ignore that last comment. Everything is correct now. For the record, myfirebase was just a placeholder for my actual firebase and that was the problem. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Assuming that simpleLogin is coming from angularFire-seed, getUser() already returns a promise.